# Selenium Code not moving to next line when alert is displayed in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, alert

While running the code some of the alerts are clicked by using the below code and some of the alerts are not clicked by using the same code. When alerts displayed in which unable to click ok, coding is not even moving to the nextline (including printing statement).

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
driver.switchto().alert().accept();
```

Please provide solution.

Comment: `using the same.` did you forget a word ? What do you mean by `unable to handle`? Don't hesitate to edit your question to improve the clarity ;)

Comment: While running the code some of the alerts are clicked by using the below code and some of the alerts are not clicked by using the same code. When alerts displayed in which unable to click ok, coding is not even moving to the nextline (including printing statement).

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()); driver.switchto().alert().accept();

Comment: Version of components (especially `IEDriverServer.exe`) is going to be very important in helping to diagnose this issue.

Comment: Almost tried every version for internet explorer version 11.

Comment: can you check the code about display the alert? whether they are using the same code to display the alerts? Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Same js code  alert("xxxxx") ;